# Can't add New Work Items from the Sprint View in Boards

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-boards

**Host Details:**

OS Editon: Azure Devops server 2016
OS Build: 1607

**Azure DevOps Details:**

AZ server: 2019

**The issue:**

For one Team Project, we are requiring to have three different sub-area paths so we can place work accordingly for each team Properly to follow it.
The three sub-areas were created as follow:

[image: sub-area path created]

and visible are visible from **Bords**:

[image: New sub-areas visible from Boards]

But, and here **the issue**, the Button for creating **New Work Item** now is **Disabled**, as shown below:

[image: New Work Item button dissabled]

Also

[image]

How could re-enable this button?
We use this button at daily basis to create New Tasks or as required, is so weird that enabling one functionality we lost other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved each team is an independent unit and for that each will have their own setup,

Once that is corrected all works fine

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible your workflow has the work item disabled. Check your process and see if the work item type is disabled. Also on the ribbon next to View as Board, hover and click, it will give you a more detailed error message.

If the work item is disabled you will see this message.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solved by myself**

Hello Martin, thanks for reaching me out so swiftly,

I did found the issue, due to a lack in Azure DevOps documentation didn't know that when creating a new Team Project have to create the extra teams within the Project before anything else, and then is that can proceed to add define the sub-area paths in the Boards Section and then is when is possible to have First multiple teams within a team project and Second have enabled the Work Items Button for each team sprint:

[image]

See for example this MS official documentation how they don't make any clarification of it: {{ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=azure-devops }} :

[image]

Also here {{ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser }} :

[image]

So MS docs miss that point completaly!